# How to swap multiple axis of a transformation matrix

Tags: matrices, transformation

I have a transformation matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}i_{x} & j_{x} & k_{x} & t_{x}\\
i_{y} & j_{y} & k_{y} & t_{y}\\
i_{z} & j_{z} & k_{z} & t_{z}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

I need / want to create a transformation matrix or a series of transforms that will cleanly swap the axis to generate:

$$\begin{bmatrix}k_{z} & i_{z} & -j_{z} & -t_{z}\\
k_{x} & i_{x} & -j_{x} & -t_{x}\\
k_{y} & i_{y} & -j_{y} & -t_{y}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

How do i approach this?

If you were to visualize the matrices as a transformation frame, you would see it as a rotation on the X axis of 90 degrees followed by a rotation of the Y axis by -90 degrees. Which if applied, leads to the correct swapping of tx/ty/tz values but obviously not the rotation components.

Comment: When trying to convert row and column operations into matrix multiplication it's often useful to compose them out of elementary matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for. We have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}k_{z} & i_{z} & -j_{z} & -t_{z}\\
k_{x} & i_{x} & -j_{x} & -t_{x}\\
k_{y} & i_{y} & -j_{y} & -t_{y}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = \\
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&-1&0\\
-1&0&0&0\\
0&-1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}i_{x} & j_{x} & k_{x} & t_{x}\\
i_{y} & j_{y} & k_{y} & t_{y}\\
i_{z} & j_{z} & k_{z} & t_{z}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&-1&0\\
-1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: can that first matrix even be represented / constructed from a series of rotations?

Comment: @user1436508 No. One way to see that this is the case is to note that the matrix has a negative determinant

Comment: @user1436508 Also, the fact that your original matrix and target matrix have opposite signs is enough to deduce that, in general, rotations alone are insufficient.